# Django uploading images

Tags: python, django

I want to upload images in the django admin interface. During development everything works fine but when I put the files on my server it doesn't work. 
I have two different paths on my Server. One where I put all my source files and one where I put all the static files.

Path for source files: `/htdocs/files/project/`

Path for static files: `/htdocs/html/project/`

If I upload an image, then it is saved in `/htdocs/files/project/media/`. But I want to save it in `/htdocs/html/project/`. How can I change the path?

Here are my settings:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    '/var/www/ssd1257/htdocs/html/'
)
```

And here is my model:

```
class News(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    date = models.DateField(null=False, default=datetime.now)
    text = models.TextField(null=False, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="./news/")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The uploaded files are saved normally in the following path
MEDIA_URL + the path specified in “upload_to” attribute in the model class

So in your case,
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media') = “/htdocs/files/project/media”
Django will create the path if it doesn’t exits

But I didn’t get the dot in-frontront of ‘upload_to’ to path(“./news/“)

So if you want to change the path where uploaded files are stored, simply change the MEDIA_ROOT
Note, please provide the absolute full path

I guess it will be 
MEDIA_ROOT = '/var/www/ssd1257/htdocs/html/project'

Also, its better to rename the uploaded files before saving to avoid file_name conflicts

```
def get_news_image_path(instance, filename):
   path_first_component = ‘news/‘
   ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
   timestamp = millis = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
   file_name = ‘news_’ + str(instance.id) + str('_logo_image_') + timestamp + str('.') + ext
   full_path = path_first_component + file_name
   return full_path

class News(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    date = models.DateField(null=False, default=datetime.now)
    text = models.TextField(null=False, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_news_image_path)
```

Now the uploaded files will be saved in 
'/var/www/ssd1257/htdocs/html/project/news’

You are Done

In addition, also set appropriate MEDIA_URL

Ex: MEDIA_URL = “media
So when generated URL for the upload images will be
MEDIA_URL + upload_to path

Also, configure the web server to serve these URLs from appropriate locations

Comment: Thanks for your help !:)

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage    
upload_storage = FileSystemStorage(location=UPLOAD_ROOT, base_url='/') #upload root set to your project directory
class News(models.Model):
      title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
      date = models.DateField(null=False, default=datetime.now)
      text = models.TextField(null=False, blank=True)
      image = models.ImageField(upload_to='/', storage=upload_storage)
```

Comment: The current upload location is /htdocs/files/project/media . How can I change the path to /htdocs/html/project/media ?

Answer (score 0):

Self-inflicted by this setting:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Change that to:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/htdocs/html/project/'
```